# Why changing the PlaceHolder to the left doesn't work with this method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I tried, in IOS 7 to subclass an `UISearchBar` so that the place holder is always left aligned.

I did this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UITextField * tv = self.textField;

    tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft  ;
}
```

If `tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight`, then I manage to make the text to the right.

However, the text when `UISearchBar` is empty, and display the placeholder, always shows to the center.

I wonder why. I put it in `layoutSubviews` method. Hence, it should be drawn every time the control is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this using `UIAppearance`.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

Downvoters, please read this : [note from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

Note: iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue before some days ago, but there is no way to change the alignment of search bar's placeholder text, I tested with so many "SO" answer but no one was working. 
At last I decided with following Fixing.

Add some white space in Left/right *(as you want)* of placeholder text

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 6.1) {
    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"hello";
}
 else 
{
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
    // Add some white space in Left/right *(as you want)* here i added to left
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"           hello";
}
```

Comment: @JimThio - i also don't know why your code is not working but i know that i fight with it and i am not able find real problem :( so i fix it :)

Comment: Looks like the textfield that display the search is different than the textfield that display placeholder.

Comment: How does this answer left justify the placeholder text?

Comment: @rmaddy - what do you mean ?

Comment: The OP wants the placeholder to appear to the left. How does adding a bunch of spaces before the placeholder text make the placeholder appear to the left in the text field?

Comment: @rmaddy - i edited it .. it just typo dude.. :P (see my comment). If you have any idea about this issue then you can share here. It may be very helpful for me and others.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Through NSLog the searchBar's textField subviews, can get such a result:

```
<_UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView: 0x8d492e0; frame = (0 0; 304 28); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d49410>> - (null),
<UIImageView: 0x8d488a0; frame = (102.5 7.5; 12.5 12.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d48f80>> - (null),
<UISearchBarTextFieldLabel: 0x8d4b410; frame = (122.5 1; 181.5 25); text = 'hello000000'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8d4b520>>
)
```

you can see, `UISearchBarTextFieldLabel` is the UI to show placeholder, here is 'hello000000', which is a subclass of UILabel. Therefore, set searchBar's textField textAlignment will not affect placeholder position directly. And the layout of placeholder label is handled by searchBar's textField `- (void)layoutSubviews` , whereas you can't override inner textField this method.

A custom searchBar base on UIView, add your subclass of UITextField which override `- (void)layoutSubviews`, Or even add add UILabel where textfield's text is empty, remove while not. maybe a solution.

Add some my test code:

```
@interface CustomSearchBar : UIView {
}
@end

@implementation SharedSearchBar
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {        
        _textField = [[SearchTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6, frame.size.width-20, frame.size.height-12)];
        _textField.leftView = UIImageViewNamed(@"search_glass");
        [self addSubview:_textField];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@interface SearchTextField : UITextField

@end

@implementation SearchTextField
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *lb = (UILabel *)subView;
            lb.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            lb.text = @"123123";
            CGRect frame = lb.frame;
            frame.origin.x = textFiled.frame.size.width-frame.size.width;
            lb.frame = frame;
            break;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

[image: This is empty result:]